# Regex for crontab validation

Tags: bash, shell-script, cron, regular-expression

I need to check in bash whether an entry into the crontab file is valid. Is there a `crontab` command switch?

I can extract individual lines and try to control individual items through regex, but I don't know how to check the type of records, e.g. `10,20,30`, `*/2`, `Jan-May,Dec` -- any advice on how to do it?

```
read -a cron <<< "${cron_tab}"  
if [[ "${cron[0]}" =~ ^(@(reboot|yearly|annualy|monthly|weekly|daily|hourly))$ ]]; then
        ...

    #check minutes
    if [[ "${cron[0]}" =~ ^([*]|[0-5][0-9]{1})$ ]]; then
        ...
    #check hours
    if [[ "${cron[1]}" =~ ^([*]|[01]?[0-9]|2[0-3])$ ]]; then
    ...
    #check days
    if [[ "${cron[2]}" =~ ^([*]|[0-2]?[0-9]|3[0-1])$ ]]; then
        ...         
    #check months
    if [[ "${cron[3]}" =~ ^([*]|[0]?[0-9]|1[0-2])$ ]]; then
    ...
    #check days of week
    if [[ "${cron[4]}" =~ ^([*]|[0]?[0-7])$ ]]; then
    ...
```

Comment: Does it _have_ to be in bash? Could we use awk or perl or other tools? Also, how is `${cron}` being set? You seem to be assuming that commands can't have arguments, what if your cron line is `@reboot echo a b c d e f g`?

Comment: You're right, check the record by the number of items it was not a good idea to remake it. Awk can be used.

Comment: You mentioned `@reboot`, does that mean you're on a Linux system? With Perl installed?

Comment: Yes, this is Linux. Perl is installed.

Answer (score 5):

The most reliable way to test whether a crontab line is valid is to ask the `crontab` utility.

Most `crontab` utilities don't have an option to only validate and not change the crontab. You can call `crontab -e` to set the crontab, and if this succeeds restore the previous content, but this is not robust: if the input is valid, a job that it contains could be started if the clock happens to go past a minute before you restore the previous content, and if someone else modifies the crontab at the same time, one or both operations will be disrupted.

So what you can do is call `crontab` in its own playground. One way to do this is to run it in a [chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot) — a  real one or a fake one. You can call [fakechroot](http://fakechroot.alioth.debian.org/) to create a fake chroot environment without being root. Here's how to populate it, starting from an empty directory:

```
mkdir -p bin etc tmp var/spool/cron/crontabs
echo "temp:x:$(id -u):65534:Temporary user:/:/none" >etc/password
touch var/spool/cron/crontabs
cp /usr/bin/crontab /bin/sh /bin/sleep /bin/cat bin/
cat "${cron_tab}" >input

echo n | env -i EDITOR='sleep 1; cat /input >' fakechroot -d /lib/ld-linux.so.2 -- chroot . /bin/crontab -e
```

Tweak the location of the executables as appropriate for your system. `/lib/ld-linux.so.2` is the dynamic loader; I gave the location for Linux on x86_32, use `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` for Linux on x86_64, etc. You can find the location by running `ldd /bin/cat` and noting the one for which a single absolute path is given.

The last command returns 0 if the crontab is valid (it also modifies `var/spool/cron/crontabs/temp`). It returns an error status and prints an error message if the crontab is invalid.

`sleep 1` ensures that `crontab` won't think that the file hasn't changed (some implementations check the modification time, and some filesystems only have 1-second granularity for file timestamps). To avoid the delay, you could copy the `touch` utility instead of `sleep`, and arrange to change the timestamp by setting (if you have GNU `touch`)

```
EDITOR='f () { cat /input >"$1"; touch -d "+ 1 second" }; f'
```